# What do you do to both sides to turn $1/x=1/2$ into $x=2$?

Tags: algebra-precalculus

Logically it makes sense that $x=2$ just by looking at it, but what do you do to both sides to flip both the fractions?

to get $x$ on it's own you need to multiply $1/x$ by $x^2$

but if you multiply both sides by $x^2$

you end up with $x=x^2/2$

Comment: take multiplicative inverse both side

Comment: You multiply both sides by $x$ and then multiply both sides by 2. Alternatively, you just reciprocate both sides.

Comment: How did you conclude $x = 1/27$ by multiplying by $x^2$?

Comment: that is one possible way

Comment: And how did you get $x = 27x^2$? by that process? The correct result would have been $x = (1/2) x^2$.

Comment: @ T. Bongers yeah you're right, the biggest brain fart, I'm currently doing a problem and I mixed the two

Comment: Just in case you're not aware of the following identity: $1/(1/x)=x$ for all nonzero $x$.

Comment: You don't want to turn 1/x to x.  You want to turn 1/x to 2.  You don't want to turn 1/2 to 2 you want to turn 1/2 to x.  1/x = 1/2. Multiply both sides by 2.  2/x = 1.  Multiply both sides by x.  2 = x.  Transpose.  x=2.  Done.

Comment: For the future, you may notice that the observation you made is similar to equating parts, which is basically where everything in the left and right side look the same except for something, which you can assume must be equal to the equivalent 'part' on the other side of the equation.  At least it works well for bijective functions.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Given: 
$\frac{1}{x}=\frac{1}{2}$

Multiply both sides by $2x$. Then:

$2x[\frac{1}{x}=\frac{1}{2}] \implies 2=x.$

Answer (score 0):

Another way to look at it is:

$r$ is the unique number you have to multiply with $\frac{1}{r}$ to get $1$.

So if $\frac{1}{x} = \frac{1}{2}$ that unique number is both $x$ and $2$, hence $x = 2$.